# Apache Camel Restlet - Unable to extract Multipart data

Tags: java, apache-camel, multipartform-data, restlet

I have to use Apache Camel (2.12.4) Restlet to receive fileupload from browser and process. As my solution is not working, to simplify, at the moment I have kept my route definition very simple like so

```
from("restlet:/upload?restletMethod=POST")
.to("file:///<path.to.dir>//?fileName=<dump-file.http>");
```

Using Postman, I am uploading a simple java class file and form value with a goal to retrieve them both back. I want to be able to write class file back into a file and execute to prove successful creation.

For doing this I have written a simple utility tool, it reads the dump file using org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream; and for now is prints headers and body.

```
public class MultipartDataExtractor {

    public static final String DELIMITER = "\\r?\\n";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] boundary = "----------------------------002984755777142240671505".getBytes(); // copying from dump file
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("<path.to.dir>/<dump-file.http>"));
        parseMultipartStream(fis, boundary);
    }

    public static void parseMultipartStream(InputStream is, byte[] boundary) throws Exception {
        MultipartStream multipartStream = new MultipartStream(is, boundary, 1024 * 4, null);
        System.out.println("Trying to read multipart data");
        boolean nextPart = multipartStream.skipPreamble();
        while (nextPart) {
            String headers = multipartStream.readHeaders();
            System.out.println(String.format("headers: [%s]", headers));
            multipartStream.readBodyData(System.out);
            System.out.println("");
            nextPart = multipartStream.readBoundary();
        }
    }
}
```

I use this tool successfully on a file that I created extracting content from a servlet. On camel dumped file, it runs however fails to parse even through the content visibly looks ok. The multipartStream.skipPreamble() returns false, On debugging I find, internally it throws a MalformedException, and returns a false from catch block. The dumped file looks like so

```
----------------------------002984755777142240671505
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="HelloWorld.class"
Content-Type: application/java-vm

����4

<init>()VCodeLineNumberTablemain([Ljava/lang/String;)V
SourceFileHelloWorld.javaHello World
HelloWorldjava/lang/Objectjava/lang/SystemoutLjava/io/PrintStream;java/io/PrintStreamprintln(Ljava/lang/String;)V   *��
        %   ���



----------------------------002984755777142240671505
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

Hans Muster
----------------------------002984755777142240671505--
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. Any pointer or help will be highly appreciated.